# In an existing table with records, how do I create a new datetime2(2) column and populate it with values based on another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a VARCHAR column that looks like this:

```
Created_DTM
-----------
2020-02-05 16:26:45.00Z
2020-02-16 08:55:52.00Z
2020-04-24 15:24:01.00Z
2020-06-13 22:14:18.00Z
```

How do I write a script that will create a new column called Created_DTM_Converted and fill each record with a value so that the zulu (Z) character is gone whilst subtracting 5 hours to match my timezone?

**What I've tried:**

This query gives me the exact values I need:

```
SELECT dateadd(hh, -5, convert(datetime2(2), Created_DTM, 120)) AS Created_DTM_Converted
FROM dbo.table
```

This is the output:

```
Created_DTM_Converted
-----------
2020-02-05 11:26:45.00
2020-02-16 03:55:52.00
2020-04-24 10:24:01.00
2020-06-13 17:14:18.00
```

But I don't know how to write a script that can be executed once and will make this a permanently added column. How do I go about doing so?

Comment: Do you want the values of your new column to change if the value in the existing `created_DTM` column changes? Or is this a one-off exercise  (for example, you intend to drop the existing column)?

Comment: The latter is correct: I intend on dropping the existing column later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned in the commentary that you intend to calculate the new column from the old column, and intend to drop the old column later, you won't be able to use Tim's answer of a computed column.

Therefore you will need to execute this process in two steps. First add the column, then populate it with values. You can drop the original column later as a third step.

```
alter table dbo.table add Created_DTM_Converted datetime2(2) null;
go

update dbo.table
set    Created_DTM_Converted = dateadd(hh, -5, convert(datetime2(2), Created_DTM, 120));
```

Once you have populated the column, you can optionally alter its definition to not allow nulls:

```
alter table dbo.table alter column Created_DTM_Converted datetime2(2) not null;
```

Comment: A computed column could also be used, because of course it can also be dropped.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OK... so let me understand your thinking here. OP has data they need. It is currently stored in a column which they intend to drop. They create a computed column to store a certain new representation of their data, based on that existing column. At some point in the future they drop the computed column, and then the original column. I have one question, Tim. Where did their data go?

Answer (score 2):

You could alter your table and add this new column as a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table
ADD COLUMN Created_DTM_Converted AS DATEADD(hh, -5, CONVERT(datetime2(2), Created_DTM, 120));
```

Note that the above computed column is *virtual*, meaning that it is not actually stored in the database, but rather is computed on the fly when it is accessed.

By the way, a potentially easier way of subtracting 5 hours might just be to take the first 22 characters of the timestamp:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, -5, LEFT(Created_DTM, 22))
FROM dbo.table;
```

This also seems to be working.

**Edit:**

I recommend *against* dropping the original `Created_DTM` column for several reasons.  First, it represents original source data, and it is a generally good idea to keep as much state as possible.  Second, assuming new records would be getting inserted in this original format, then you would want to maintain this column.  In this case, building some sort of view on top of your table would be appropriate.

Comment: Per additional commentary provided by the OP, they intend to drop the original column, so a computed column cannot be used here.

Comment: The whole point of a virtual column is being able to view your data a certain way without committing any space to it.  With a non persistent computed column there is nothing to "drop."

Comment: OP intends to drop the *existing* `Created_DTM` column. This is not specified in the original question, it's in the subsequent commentary, wherein I guessed that the likely use case here is that they have made the sensible decision to store `datetime` values as actual `datetime` values rather than varchar and are cleaning up a bit of tech debt which will ultimately involve dropping the `varchar` column, but in doing so they obviously want to preserve their existing data.

Comment: @allmhuran you're correct, the column is currently varchar and has been collecting data in that manner for too long, so I'm trying to clean it up. I would prefer to actually store the data in a dedicated 'datetime' column and delete the varchar column at a later time.

Comment: @Nixu OK...but what happens when new data comes in later on, and the column has been removed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh I should have clarified — I’m reprogramming the app so that it saves dates both in datetime format and varchar (at least for now)